# get max date by comparing total amount with amount in another table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have two tables tableA(S.no.,amount) and tableB(Id,paid_amt,trxn_dt)

```
   tableA                tableB
S.no.  amount     Id    paid_amt    trxn_dt  
1       500       1       200      2015-01-01   
2       500       2       300      2015-02-10
3       500       3       500      2015-04-10
4       500       4       1000     2015-10-10
```

Now i need a query to get the output as follows:

```
S.no.    amount          trxn_dt
 1        500           2015-02-10
 2        500           2015-04-10
 3        500           2015-10-10
 4        500           2015-10-10
```

I need to compare the sum of paid_amt from tableB to match each amount of tableA and get the max trxn_dt according to it. i.e (200+300)=500  so get max(trxn_dt) i.e 2015-02-10. Similarly for s.no.2 get get max(trxn_dt) as 2015-04-10 and for last one 1000 has been paid on 2015-10-10 so get max(trxn_dt) as 2015-10-10 for both s.no. 3 and 4. i.e i have to get the trxn_dt of the exact paid amount according to s.no. I am able to do this using resultset in java but it is time consuming for table containing lots of data.I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: Sound quite confusing

Comment: table A represents installment plan table and table B represents transaction table. Now i need to get the latest trxn_dt for each installment paid from table B. For e.g . amount 500 was paid with two transactions 1st on 2015-01-01 and second on 2015-02-10. So the first output for 500 amount is 2015-02-10. Hope this clears it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements seem complex but if you calculate the running totals first, it's a simple comparison.

Find the first running_total from b that has covered the running_total from a:

```
WITH 
  rta AS
    ( SELECT [S.no], amount,
             running_total = SUM(amount) OVER 
                                 (ORDER BY [S.no]
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                           AND CURRENT ROW)
      FROM tableA
    ),
  rtb AS
    ( SELECT trxn_dt, id,
             running_total = SUM(paid_amt) OVER 
                                 (ORDER BY trxn_dt, id
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                           AND CURRENT ROW)
      FROM tableB
    )
SELECT
    a.[S.no], a.amount, b.trxn_dt
FROM rta AS a
  OUTER APPLY 
    ( SELECT TOP (1) b.trxn_dt
      FROM rtb AS b
      WHERE a.running_total <= b.running_total
      ORDER BY b.running_total, b.trxn_dt, b.id
    ) AS b ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/PEMRA28867).